# When is a locally presentable category (locally) cartesian-closed?

Tags: ct.category-theory, locally-presentable-categories, cartesian-closed-categories

Let $\kappa$ be a regular cardinal. A category $\mathscr C$ is locally $\kappa$-presentable iff it is the free completion of a small $\kappa$-cocomplete category under $\kappa$-filtered colimits. Is there a known characterisation of the categories $\mathscr C$ that are:

1. locally $\kappa$-presentable and cartesian-closed;
2. locally $\kappa$-presentable and locally cartesian-closed;

in terms of being the free cocompletion of a small $\kappa$-cocomplete category *with particular structure* under $\kappa$-filtered colimits?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the [Day reflection theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Day%27s+reflection+theorem) when viewing the LFP as a reflective subcategory of a presheaf topos. For the locally Cartesian closed case, I guess you would just apply some fibred category variant of the Day reflection theorem as each $$\mathcal{E}/X$$ is a reflective subcategory of the Cartesian closed $$[C,Set]/X$$.

Comment: This answer is coherent with *Street*'s Thm. 3.11 in **Cosmoi of internal categories**.

Comment: Day's reflection theorem tells us that the LFP category $\mathscr C$ is cartesian-closed iff the reflector is cartesian: how can we characterise the corresponding category of finitely presentable objects for $\mathscr C$ using this?

Answer (score 1):

I might try to improve my answer later this day. For the moment, a sufficient condition was given by *Pedicchio and Borcerux* in **A characterization of quasi-toposes**, JoA 139 (1991).

> Prop 4.1. If $C$ is an elementary topos, then $\mathsf{Lex}(C^\circ,\mathsf{Set})$ is cartesian closed.

Comment: Thank you; I was unaware of this reference. Just a note that you're missing "locally" in the statement of Prop. 4.1.