# Why is $\rm{Cat}$ a Cartesian-closed category?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, locally-presentable-categories

I am interested in naturally occurring symmetric closed monoidal structures on locally presentable categories.

Two general examples:

1. Grothendieck topos with Cartesian structure. Here, for example, $\mathrm{Set}, \mathrm{sSet}$, smooth sets, etc.
2. [Category algebras over a commutative algebraic theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/commutative+algebraic+theory#ClosedMonoidalStructureOnAlgebras). Here, for example, $R\text{-}\mathrm{Mod}, \mathrm{Set}_*$.

I think, it's easy to see that they can be combined into one super example: the category of algebras over a commutative monad on a Grothendieck topos (in the case of a trivial monad, we have the topos itself; we can also consider pointed objects in any topos, in particular we get some sorts of pointed spaces).

Separate from this business is the category $\mathrm{Cat}$.

> Is there a natural family of [limit theories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/essentially+algebraic+theory), including $\rm{Cat}$ theory, which are Cartesian closed for some general reason? And $\mathrm{Pos}$ (category of posets)?

Comment: It's hard to know what sort of answer would satisfy you. I'm going to guess that you could grind through a proof if you had to, so that what you want is some sort of conceptual reason. Here's one attempt: via the nerve functor N, Cat embeds fully faithfully into simplicial sets, and are characterized as s-sets satisfying "Segal conditions". Meanwhile, s-sets form a cartesian closed category (since, e.g., it's a topos). It then suffices to check that for a category C and simplicial set X, that NC^X is also the nerve of a category, by showing it too satisfies the Segal conditions.

Comment: Pos can piggyback on Cat because (like the Segal conditions) what it means for a category to be a preorder or poset can be described by certain limit conditions. One could say that Cat is an "exponential ideal" of s-sets (if C is a category and X is an s-set, then the s-set C^X is a category), and likewise, Pos is an exponential ideal of Cat.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Thanks for your attention! Perhaps I didn't articulate well what I mean: I would like to put $\rm{Cat}$ into a natural family of locally presentable categories that are Cartesian-closed for some general reason. I'll add this clarification to the text of the question.

Comment: And I'm trying to sketch a general reason: roughly speaking, if you start with a cartesian closed category, and if the objects of certain full subcategory are definable as those objects c that satisfy certain limit properties (like Segal conditions), then exponentials c^x will also satisfy those conditions since (-)^x preserves limits. (I guess you also need that the full embedding preserves products. This is true for the nerve functor, for instance.)

Comment: One natural way to answer the question would be to show that $Cat$ has some sort of universal property _qua_ cartesian closed category. For instance, it might be enlightening to try to understand the category $Fun^{L,\times}(Cat, \mathcal K)$ of functors $Cat \to \mathcal K$ which preserve colimits and finite products, where $\mathcal K$ is an arbitrary cartesian closed locally presentable category. It may also be relevant to mention that [there are exactly two monoidal biclosed structures on $Cat$](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(80)90082-1).

Comment: Thank you! I realized that I was interested in the explanation from a syntactic point of view (as in my examples before). I somewhat reflected that clarification in the question now, I apologize. From this point of view, $\rm{Cat}$ is still just lucky to be embedded that way in simplicial sets (or rather, I don't know of a class of limit theories that have that property).

Comment: I like this question.  I feel like @ToddTrimble’s comments gives a good conceptual reason why Cat is CCC, for a particular presentation of Cat (the simplicial one) — and the comments would make a nice answer — but like @ Aivazian, I would also be interested to know if there’s a way to explain it in terms of *the traditional algebraic presentation* of Cat (or perhaps I should say, one of the several traditional such presentations).

Comment: It fits into the class of locally presentable categories whose Cartesian product has a right adjoint.

Comment: I think there's a joke answer one can give here. It is not hard to check that the reflector of any reflective exponential ideal – such as $\textbf{Cat}$ in $\textbf{sSet}$ – preserves cartesian products. But a reflector that preserves cartesian monoids is a commutative monad (with respect to the cartesian monoidal structure, of course). Therefore it is covered by your "super example".

Comment: Not an answer, but Joyal proposed the name "paratopos" for reflective subcats of presheaf cats where the reflector only preserves finite products (rather than finite limits as for toposes). As pointed out above, this preservation of finite products by the reflector is equivalent to the subcategory being an exponential ideal. Here's a video where Joyal makes this suggestion: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmCh9KwrQq8

Comment: The category of small semicategories is not Cartesian-closed. So the identity maps play an important role.

Comment: Is the cartesian closedness of $Cat$ more mysterious than the cartesian closedness of compactly-generated spaces, or less mysterious?

Comment: Compactly generated spaces are not locally presentable categories, are they? So they don't apply to my question, if that's what you're talking about. I position Grothendieck topoi here as initial contexts for doing mathematics. Then we can interpret certain theories in them. It turns out that there is a common pattern: the category of algebras of a commutative algebraic theory (in a Grothendieck topos) has a natural closed monoidal structure.

Comment: This explains many examples of closed monoidal categories that we encounter in mathematics, but not $\mathrm{Cat}$. I wonder what deep pattern (class of theories) is behind this particular example.

Comment: If the goal is to find deep patterns, then it may be a bit artificial to restrict to the presentable case. At any rate, $\Delta$-generated spaces are locally presentable and cartesian closed, and perhaps just as mysterious as $Cat$ in that regard.

Comment: I mean patterns among essentially algebraic theories such as commutativity. Yes, I also wanted to suggest delta-generated spaces when you wrote about compactly generated ones. Only they are not a finitary theory, in this sense $\mathrm{Cat}$ seems more interesting/fundamental.

Comment: I believe this is essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/374753/when-is-a-locally-presentable-category-locally-cartesian-closed).